# Get all fields from one side after join if schema unknown

Tags: apache-pig

I have 2 relations, without schema:

```
rel1 = load '$path1' using PigStorage('\t');
rel2 = load '$path2' using PigStorage('\t');
```

I want to join them by first field and get all fields from `rel1`. How can I do that with Pig? I have no luck with using `rel1.$0..` syntax:

```
filtered = foreach (join rel1 by $0, join rel2 by $0) generate ???
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed it using `cogroup` expression:

define FirstTupleFromBag datafu.pig.bags.FirstTupleFromBag;

```
rel1 = load '$path1' using PigStorage('\t');
rel2 = load '$path2' using PigStorage('\t');

filtered = foreach (cogroup rel1 by $0, rel2 by $0) generate flatten(rel1.$0), flatten(rel2.$0), flatten(FirstTupleFromBag(rel1, null));

result = foreach filtered generate $2..;
```

I use `flatten` for `rel2` and `rel1` key fields to make `cogroup` act like an inner join.

While this works, I think, there should be an easier solution for that.